# jQuery Change CSS via Class Click

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

This is driving me crazy, I've tried this multiple ways and nothing is working. Anyone able to help me?

jQuery:

```
$(".FCChatControl").click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("rel");
    var wnd = $(id);
    if (wnd.style.marginBottom == "-1px") {
        $(wnd).css({"margin-bottom": "-236px"});
    } else {
        $(wnd).css({"margin-bottom": "-1px"});
    }
});
```

Executed From:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="#item.OwnerID#" id="FCChatControlID" class="FCChatControl">
    <div id="cw-header">
        <h1>#item.Nickname#</h1>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: What errors does the console show?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'marginBottom' of undefined

Comment: `.style.marginBottom` is plain JavaScript and you're passing a jQuery object to it.

Comment: How can I check to see if an elements CSS is a certain value in jQuery? I've only seen how to set it.

Comment: Just read the manual.
http://api.jquery.com/css/

$(wnd).css("margin-bottom");// With px characters at end

Comment: There is no `$('#item.OwnerID#')`, which is what you're assigning to wnd.

Comment: In the code you posted you have a rel of `#item.OwnerID#` but the following h1 has text of `#item.Nickname#`.

Comment: what element needs the css?

Comment: The `wnd` variable refers to a jQuery wrapped object, not a DOM node.  Only jQuery methods apply.  If you want the node so you can grab it's `.style`, do something like `.get(0)`, IIRC.  (as in `var node = wnd.get(0)`)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're after, but here's now you'd check a CSS property and act on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/DxNA3/

```
$('.FCChatControl').click(function() {
    if ($(this).css('margin-bottom') == "-1px") {
        $(this).css('margin-left', '50px'); // demo
    }
});
```

By the way, your `else` clause would seem to be pointless, so I've removed it.